# Enable/disable drop down list based on another drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 drop down list

```
<select id="servergroup" multiple="multiple">             
  <option value="P1">P1</option>
  <option value="P2">P2</option>
  <option value="P3">P3</option>
  <option value="P4">P4</option>
</select>

<select id="servername" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="s597ap233">s597ap233</option>
  <option value="s597dp392">s597dp392</option>
  <option value="s397dp095">s397dp095</option> 
</select>
```

I want that the second drop down list should get enabled only if we choose a value in the first drop down list. It should again get disabled if we deselect the value from the first drop down list.
May I know how can this be achieved using jQuery?

Comment: Would be interesting to know if this affect can be achieved in a non-JS way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `disabled` attribute and using JavaScript, you can set it as `false` or `true`

```js
function check(){
  if(document.getElementById('servergroup').value!='')
    document.getElementById('servername').disabled=false;
  else
    document.getElementById('servername').disabled=true;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="check()" id="servergroup" multiple="multiple">

    <option value="P1">P1</option>
    <option value="P2">P2</option>
    <option value="P3">P3</option>
    <option value="P4">P4</option>
    </select>
    <select disabled id="servername" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="s597ap233">s597ap233</option>
    <option value="s597dp392">s597dp392</option>
    <option value="s397dp095">s397dp095</option> 
    </select>
```

Comment: I am using jQuery for multi select drop down list with checkbox because of which the above feature is not working. May I know what can be done.

Comment: This is the script because of which r=the above code is not executing properly. May I know what is wrong in it.
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#servergroup').multiselect({
            buttonWidth: '500px'
        });
    }); 
</script>

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#bonusVoucher').prop('disabled',false);
jQuery('#bonusVoucher').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Use selectpicker like this and the most **IMPORTANT** part is this:

**Note: Place your bootsrap selectpicker script after jquery script.**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution.

```js
function change() {
  if ($('#servergroup option:selected').length) {
    $('#servername').attr('disabled', false);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="servergroup" multiple="multiple" onchange='change()'>
    <option value="P1">P1</option>
    <option value="P2">P2</option>
    <option value="P3">P3</option>
    <option value="P4">P4</option>
</select>

<select id="servername" multiple="multiple" disabled>
    <option value="s597ap233">s597ap233</option>
    <option value="s597dp392">s597dp392</option>
    <option value="s397dp095">s397dp095</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First add

```
<option value="-1"> -Select Server Group- </option>
```

and

```
<option value="-1"> -Select Server Name- </option>
```

to Your Dropdown boxes respectively.

We can achieve requested actions using JQuery as Follows:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    //making serverName Dropdown box disabled by default.
    $('#servername').prop('disabled', true);

    $('#servergroup').change(function ()
    {
        if($(this).val == "-1")
        {
           $('#servername').val = "-1";
           $('#servername').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else
        {   
          $('#servername').prop('disabled', false); 
        }  
    });
});
```